# What is going on with my star jasmine?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, vines, wilt

I purchased a star jasmine plant a few weeks ago and since then the flowers have died and the leaves have either drooped or turned brown. I was hoping it was just transplant shock since I repotted the jasmine when I got it, but it has not seemed to change in the few weeks since then.

I have been giving it about a pint of water every 3 or 4 days. When I check the soil it is often dry on the very top, but it is always moist - not wet - underneath the very top. Can anyone provide any suggestions? As someone who is new to owning plants I would really appreciate any advice!

Side note: the jasmine is in a self-watering planter and I gave it some 4-10-3 root stimulator fertilizer about a week ago. The plant still looks the same though.

[image: full jasmine image]

[image: jasmine zoom]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your plant is suffering from drought - when you potted it up into a larger container, it needed time for the roots to spread into the new potting soil you surrounded the root ball with. Whilst that's happening, it's important to keep the soil reasonably moist. The small amount you used every 3 or 4 days doesn't seem like anywhere near enough, unless the climate where you are is extremely cool and relatively damp.

With regard to self watering pots, my experience of these has been pretty negative, such that I now never use them. The soil is usually too dry and drainage is poor, and for a plant that has just been put in a much larger pot, they really don't work very well. I prefer to use a pot with drainage holes in the bottom - depending on your air temperatures, you'd need to give it a good soak now and then probably water with a gallon or three every couple of days if your weather is hot, though its difficult to be certain about the frequency and amount because I have no idea where you are in the world. Do not use any fertilisers or other chemicals whilst the plant is in drought - what it needs is water.